# Change a date into a Financial Year

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, financial

**Financial Year Date Conversion**
How do I change a date into a Financial Year format?

i.e. 30/06/2016 into 2015/2016

Comment: You should ask the question and then answer it yourself below, rather than in the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'll take note! Not sure why you have down rated the post. Being EOFY, it's a fitting QnA. Cheers!

Comment: @JoshSeabrook your question sounds good, but you should beef your question out, and post the answer as an answer rather than the comments :)

Comment: @Quill - Thanks! I'm currently at work doing financial year analysis and thought I'd quickly give this a go for a first time!

Answer (score 1):

Copy+Paste this into a new Cell:

=IFERROR(IF(MONTH(N3)>=7,CONCATENATE(YEAR(N3),"/",YEAR(N3)+1),CONCATENATE(YEAR(N‌​3)-1,"/",YEAR(N3))),"Issue With Date in Cell N3")

New Date: "2015/2016"

Change Cell N3 to cell with your date. Make sure the cell is in a "General" format.

Comment: It seems a perfectly good answer to me, assuming your FY ends in June.